# ssh config identities specified by IdentityFile are not forwarded by ForwardAgent

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh, ssh-config

I work in an environment where I have multiple ssh keys for multiple environments, all of which utilize a bastion host, meaning to ssh to any box in any environment, it is a 2-step hop, first to the bastion, and the second to the target box, and my ssh identity has to be carried with me the whole way.

I know that both ssh and .ssh/config have options to forward all of your current ssh identities with you to the bastion host, such that you can re-use them there:

`ssh -A IPADDRESS` and `ForwardAgent`

Additionally, I know that .ssh/config has the `IdentityFile` option which allows me to specify which ssh key is used depending on the host that I am trying to connect to. However, what I have noticed is that any identities used by the IdentityFile option are not forwarded by the `ForwardAgent` - I make it to the bastion host, but without my key and I cannot ssh to the next box.

The only way I have been able to accomplish this so far is to manually add the identity that I need to use with `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa[1-10]`, and then to ssh using either `ForwardAgent` or `ssh -A`. However, this can be a pain when I have many identities that I need to switch between.

Is there a way I can accomplish all of this using just the ssh config file??

Answer (score 2):

A neater way of doing the `ProxyCommand` above is to use `ProxyJump`; your SSH config will look something like this:

```
Host bastion.host
  User user1
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_bastion

Host remote.host
  User user2
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_remote
  ProxyJump bastion.host
```

Answer (score 1):

You need :

```
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_bastion
AddKeysToAgent yes
ForwardAgent yes
```

Check `man ssh_config | less +/AddKeysToAgent`

Comment: I just tried this and it looks like exactly what I wanted except that on one of my Host configurations where I would like to carry two ssh identities with me to the bastion, it looks like its only carrying the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use a ProxyCommand ? Let's say you want to connect as user2@remote.host by going transparently through the user1@bastion.host account. The following config achieves just that :

```
Host bastion.host
  User user1
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_bastion

Host remote.host
  User user2
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_remote
  ProxyCommand ssh bastion.host -W %h:%p
```

Another nice property of this setup is that it allows other commands (such as git, sshfs, rsync, ...) to connect to remote.host "directly" through the bastion host, using the same credentials.

edit: In your setup, every host shares the same bastion, so you can even factor the ProxyCommand out with a wildcard Host before adding more specific ones :

```
Host remote.*
  ProxyCommand ssh bastion.host -W %h:%p
Host remote.host1
  IdentityFile ...
Host remote.host2
   ....
```

Comment: This also looks like a great solution, thanks!